# Is there any way to match all files in subdirectories in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is there any way to match all files in sub-directories in gitlab?
I have to make rules with changes in directory with alot of sub-directories. Are there any way (using wildcards for example), to fit any file in any subdiretory in gitlab CI?

```
somedir/*
```

Is this fit only first-level files?

Comment: Hey there,
do you mean in the `changes`-rule part of a pipeline job?

Comment: yes, exactly, this is what I mean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is: You can use `somedir/**/*` to recursively match the directory and all it's subdirectory to check for changes.

You can find more information in the [official documentation in the only:changes / except:changes chapter](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#onlychanges--exceptchanges). (e.g. you can also use variables etc.)

These rules however are also applicable in the `rules.changes` section of a Gitlab-Pipeline.